# Как сгруппировать данные и не потерять значения используя словарь?

Tags: python, парсер, анализ-данных

Не понимаю, как распарсить и не потерять значения используя словарь.

### Пример

Входные данные:

```
5
temperature,speed,RPM,population
10 50 6 7
RPM,population
6 32
temperature,speed
10 6
power,power,speed
1 2 6
speed,torque,torque,torque,power
1 2 3 4 1
```

Ожидаемый выход:

```
RPM 2*6
population 7 32
power 2*1 2
speed 1 2*6 50
temperature 2*10
torque 2 3 4
```

Моя функция, которая парсит, но я теряю повторяющиеся значения:

```
def F(N):
    i = 0
    data = {}
    data2 = {}
    while N != i:
        a = input().split(',')
        b = input().split()
        data = dict(zip(a, b))
        data2.update(data)
        i += 1
    return data2

N = int(input())
print(F(N))
```

Направьте на путь, как сгруппировать данные что бы нечего не потерять

Comment: откуда вы будете получать данные - из файла?

Comment: Нет, стандартный вход. Как с клавиатуры

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict


def parse_names_n_vals(names_str, vals_str, data=defaultdict(int)):
    names = names_str.strip().split(",")
    vals = [int(i) for i in vals_str.strip().split()]
    for name,val in zip(names, vals):
        data[name] += val
    return data

data = defaultdict(int)
N = int(input())
    
for i in range(N):
    names_str = input()
    vals_str = input()
    data = parse_names_n_vals(names_str, vals_str, data)
```

---

результат (`defaultdict`):

```
In [18]: data
Out[18]:
defaultdict(int,
            {'temperature': 20,
             'speed': 63,
             'RPM': 12,
             'population': 39,
             'power': 4,
             'torque': 9})
```

результат (обычный `dict`)

```
In [19]: dict(data)
Out[19]:
{'temperature': 20,
 'speed': 63,
 'RPM': 12,
 'population': 39,
 'power': 4,
 'torque': 9}
```

---

Если в ваших данных могут встречаться нецелые значения то лучше использовать `float()` вместо `int()`:

```
vals = [float(i) for i in vals_str.strip().split()]
```

---

**UPD:** вариант функции без использования `defaultdict`:

```
def parse_names_n_vals(names_str, vals_str, data={}):
    names = names_str.strip().split(",")
    vals = [int(i) for i in vals_str.strip().split()]
    for name,val in zip(names, vals):
        data[name] = data[name] + val if name in data else val
    return data
```